# MYSQL where clause causes syntax error

Tags: mysql, syntax, where-clause, clause

I just cannot find what is wrong with this simple statement:

```
$stat_qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stats WHERE group=$galgroup") or die("STATS ERROR: ".mysql_error()); $stat = mysql_fetch_array($stat_qry);
```

i just get: "STATS ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group=1' at line 1"

i cannot get it to work with the 'where' clause, if i remove 'where' it works but just lists everything in the database

Comment: If i got this error, first i would first print the query

Comment: Wrap \`group\` with back ticks because it is a reserved word

Comment: Better idea: Don't use reserved words as column/table identifiers. And see about sql-injection, PHP's deprecated mysql API and prepared statements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GROUP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html) is a reserved word so it needs to be between back tick ``
Also, if `$galgroup` can be a string and not only a number, you need to add quotes arround it :

```
$stat_qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stats WHERE `group`='$galgroup'") or 
die("STATS ERROR: ".mysql_error()); $stat = mysql_fetch_array($stat_qry);
```

Comment: i cant believe thats all it took, i spent all day trying to figure this out, recreated my tables, rewrote my code... argh. Thank you very much